# How to create Excel file from Excel template file using MS Graph API?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to create regular Excel files (.xlsx, .xlsm) from an Excel template file (.xltm) via the MS Graph API.

I didn't find anything in the docs (only to convert into PDF).
I tried to copy the file and changed the extension of the target file, but this results in a corrupted file.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 0):

Graph API doesn't support to create directly blank Excel file or create Excel file from a template. What I know Graph API cannot even read .xltm or .xltx files.